# Using Dragino hat to send gps data in packet every time a packet sends

Tags: gps

I have a sensor network under construction using Raspi 3s and Dragino LoraWan/GPS hats to send gas sensor data back to a Dragino Shield gateway. I now want to send the current gps location from the Dragino hat and put it in the packet every time it sends. I will deal with the packet structure, but I am not sure where to start with pulling the data. I have confirmed the GPS works with GPSD, but I cant work that into the C code I have driving the sender. My packet size allocated for the GPS right now is 64 bytes. I am working with 915MHz, and I would like to keep it all SPI. 
Thank you guys and I hope to upload my code shortly as the 915Mhz Dragino Hat for the Raspi seems to be very unsupported and required a lot of code writing and modification to get to work.

Comment: This sounds like an interesting problem! Just as a thought, it occurs to me that helping with a meaningful answer will require that someone have a fairly deep background in several areas (Dragino, GPS, etc). I wonder if you'd have better results if you could re-cast the question such that it didn't require someone have all of that specialized background?

Comment: Youre right. All I really need is someone who knows how to use GPSD to output the current gps location when prompted, in C